# Timezone is wrong in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-18.04, openldap

The time zone on the "modifyTimestamp" "pwdChangedTime" attribute of the users on openldap appears as UTC. The time zone on the OpenLDAP server (Ubuntu 18.04.4) is EEST. For this reason, the user attributes (modifyTimestamp, pwdChangedTime) on OpenLDAP show 3 hours back. How can I change the time zone UTC on the attributes of users on OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 2):

The LDAP standard specify that these attributes are generalizedTime and should use the Zulu timezone (aka UTC). It's up to the client to adjust and compute the time related to their own timezone.
This is extremely important when replication between servers is involved as servers may be in different timezones.